# TryParse for DynamicExpression.ParseLambda

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a function that evaluates a DynamicLinq expression.  While the expression itself is valid, the Parameter objects it has available to use may not always be what it needs.

I would like some method of checking if I have all the Parameters available that the expression needs before actually executing it.  Currently the best option I have found is to wrap it in a try-catch and ignore the missing param exception.

```
var ValidLambdaExpression = "ObjectType.Attribute == \"testvalue\" && ObjectType2.Attribute == \"testvalue2\"";

var paramObjects = new List<System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression>();
var p = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjectType), "ObjectType");
    paramObjects.Add(p);

var lam = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(paramObjects.ToArray(), null, ValidLambdaExpression);
//var lambody = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.Parse(null, ValidLambdaExpression);
//var lam = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(lambody, paramObjects);
var result = DataValidation.ToBoolean(lam.Compile().DynamicInvoke(data));
```

In the block of code above, the `ValidLambdaExpression` variable may be referencing objects that do not exist in the data array.  If that happens both the `ParseLambda` and `Parse` lines blow up.  I have not found any method of parsing the lambda then checking for missing parameters, or even required parameters.

This block will blow up with the error:

> ParseException -> Unknown identifier 'ObjectType2'

At the time of execution paramObjects gets dynamically built, it is not hard coded, so I do not know what objects will be put into it.

Does anyone have a better method "in terms of speed" of validating what parameters the Lambda needs before parsing it?

Comment: What is `ValidLambdaExpression`? Where did it come from? What is its type? What is `mod.ModuleValue` and what does it have to do with the lambda? What error do you get?

Comment: ValidLambdaExpression is any valid input, really doesn't matter where it came from, it represents input.  Those overloads only take Strings, so that variable is a string type.  The error itself also doesn't matter for the purposes of this question, since this question is just about validating input.  However, the error I am targeting is: ParseException -> Unknown identifier 'xxxx'. mod.ModuleValue is again, just input, I corrected that to ValidLambdaExpression to remove any confusion it caused.

Comment: I updated the code example removing some of the complexity as it was apparently distracting from the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though no one had a solution for this problem.  Here is the work-around I ended up coming up with.

At the time the Lambda expression was being built, I knew which objects were being put into it, even if I did not have that information by the time I needed to use the expression.

So I ended up prefixing the expression with a csv list of objects so I could gain access to them in the method that was using the expression.

The expression ended up looking like this:

ObjType1,ObjType2,ObjType3|ObjType1.Attribute == ObjType2.Attribute

Then I wrote a wrapper around the DynamicExpressionParser that was able to parse this string and make some intelligent decisions off of it before trying to invoke the expression.